# Getting last li not containing particular class

Tags: css, less

I am trying to write a css rule in my less file where I want to find the last `li` element which doesn't have particular class. This is how my `ul` renders

```
<ul>
   <li></li>
   <li></li> <!––I want to get this one-->
   <li class="another-instance"></li>
   <li class="another-instance"></li>
</ul>
```

And this is how I am tring to get it

```
ul.tree li:last-child:not(.another-instance) {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work! 
I tried another version of it like this as well

```
ul.tree li:not(.another-instance):last-child {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

But both of them doesn't work.
I know the rule that I am writing is converted like

`return all the last li's that doesn't have another-instance class`

But I am not getting how to write the rule for my requirement.

Any help?

Comment: last-child does not work like that.  last-child and first child return the last and first items of their parents.  Not last and first childs matching a selector.

Comment: I would rather suggest you do it by jQuery or JS.